# How do I update an object within an array using findIndex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of strings. I want to loop through this array and create a new array that houses each string and the frequency it appears. So, if the string appears more than once the `frequency` value in the new array gets updated.

From an array that looks like:

```
let strArr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
```

The desired result would be:

```
termsArr = [
  {term: "Apple", frequency: 2},
  {term: "Orange", frequency: 1},
  {term: "Banana", frequency: 2},
  {term: "Pear", frequency: 1}
]
```

I am trying to use `findIndex()` to check if the `termsArr` has a matching term in it already (and if yes update the frequency value), but it is failing saying `term` is not defined. I don't know why this is.

My full code:

```
let strArr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
let termsArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
  let arrItem = strArr[i];
  let objIndex = termsArr.findIndex((obj => obj.term == arrItem));

  if (objIndex > 0) {
    termsArr[objIndex].frequency = termsArr[objIndex].frequency + 1;
  }
  else {
    termsArr[i] = {
      term: arrItem,
      frequency: 1
    };
  }
}
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I thought it might be failing initially because the `termsArr` is empty, so modified it as such:

```
  let objIndex = 0;
  if (i < 1) {
    objIndex = termsArr.findIndex((obj => obj.term == arrItem));
  }
```

But that did not make any difference.

Comment: `objIndex` will be -1 if it can't find it. the problem might be at `if (objIndex > 0)`

Comment: `termsArr.findIndex((obj => obj.term == arrItem));` should be like this `termsArr.findIndex(obj => obj.term == arrItem);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via `array.foreach()` , `Object.keys()` and `map()`.

Refer the below code for reference :

```js
function calculateFrequency(inputArray) {
  let frequencyMap = {};

  // Count the frequency of each term
  inputArray.forEach(term => {
    frequencyMap[term] = (frequencyMap[term] || 0) + 1;
  });

  // Convert the frequency map to an array of objects
  const termsArr = Object.keys(frequencyMap).map(term => {
    return { term, frequency: frequencyMap[term] };
  });

  return termsArr;
}

const inputArray = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
const result = calculateFrequency(inputArray);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Array::reduce` one-liner:

```js
const strArr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];

const result = strArr.reduce((r, term) => ((r.map.has(term) && r.map.get(term).frequency++) || r.map.set(term, r.arr[r.arr.length] = {term, frequency: 1}), r), {map: new Map, arr: []}).arr;

console.log(...result.map(JSON.stringify));
```

Comment: since I kind of have a thing for one liners, tried one too just for fun:  `let res = [...strArr.reduce((cnt,str) => cnt.set(str,(cnt.get(str) | 0) + 1),new Map())].map(([term,cnt])=>({term,frequency:cnt}));`  Went for putting the count in a map instead of mapping the objects first.

Comment: @Me.Name i try to write a fastest code and avoid intermediate arrays

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `objIndex >= 0` instead of `objIndex > 0` to include the case when the element is found at the first index.

```js
let strArr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
let termsArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    let arrItem = strArr[i];
    let objIndex = termsArr.findIndex((obj => obj.term === arrItem));

    if (objIndex >= 0) {
        termsArr[objIndex].frequency++;
    } 
    else {
        termsArr.push({
            term: arrItem,
            frequency: 1
        });
    }
}

console.log(termsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your let strArr = should be textArr = and that will solve it. You are referencing an undefined textArr variable

[image]

Comment: Sorry you're right, but that was a typo I made when copying the code. I've fixed it now. The problem still remains

Answer (score -1):

To update an object within an array using findIndex in JavaScript, you can follow these steps:

1.Use the findIndex method to find the index of the object you want to update.

2.Once you have the index, use it to access the specific object in the array.

3.Update the properties of the object.

4.Optionally, create a new array to ensure immutability (if needed).

Here's an example:

```
let myArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Doe' }
];

// Suppose you want to update the object with id 2
let indexOfObjectToUpdate = myArray.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 2);

if (indexOfObjectToUpdate !== -1) {
  // Update the properties of the object at the found index
  myArray[indexOfObjectToUpdate].name = 'Updated Name';

  // Optionally, create a new array if you need immutability
  // newMyArray = [...myArray];

  console.log(myArray);
} else {
  console.log("Object not found in the array");
}
```

In this example, the findIndex method is used to find the index of the object with id equal to 2. If the index is found (i.e., not -1), the properties of that object are updated. You can adapt this code to your specific object properties and conditions. Remember that if you need immutability, you can create a new array using the spread operator ([...myArray]) and update the object within the new array.